# Why built in Ridge Regression does not predict true values of data in any reasonable way?

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, regression

I am working on homework task, which aims to compare self implemented ridge regression, with ADMM to built in functions of sklearn package. As much as my own implementation could be troublesome, I am stuck on interpreting built in functions output.

I am working with 3.7 version of Python, on Windows. My aim is to predict values of Y in model Y=X*Beta+Epsilon,
where Y is vector of 100 variables, X is matrix with dimensions 100x2000 of samples from multivariate normal distribution with set covariance matrix, Beta is vector with set values on 5,10 or 100 out of 2000 places
At this point I've tried any reasonable combination of passable parameters for sklearn.linear_model.Ridge, and some "easier" data for verifications purposes, but to no avail. Any help will be appriciated.

```py
# Function generating problem data:
def generate_task(n,p,cov_rho,b_val,b_k,op=0):
    " Tutaj generujemy macierz X z rozkladu normalnego o zadanych parametrach"
    mean=np.zeros(p)
    " Wersja IID"
    if op==0:
        cov=np.eye(p)
    " Wersja: malejące correlacje"
    if op==1:
        cov=np.fromfunction(lambda i,j:cov_rho**np.abs(i-j),(p,p));
    " Wersja: stale correlacje"
    if op==2:
        cov=np.eye(p)+cov_rho-np.eye(p)*(cov_rho-1)
    Chol=np.linalg.cholesky(cov)
    X=np.random.normal(0,1,(n,p))
    X=X.dot(Chol)
    X=normalise(X)
    B=(n,p+1)
    B=np.ones(B)
    B[:,1:] = X
    X=B
    " Czesc odpowiedzialna za Beta"
    Beta=np.zeros(p+1)
    m=np.arange(p+1)
    np.random.shuffle(m)
    Beta[m[1:b_k]]=b_val
    Beta=Beta.reshape(-1,1)
    " Na koncu generujemy Y zaburzone o epsilon~N(0,1)"
    ep=np.random.multivariate_normal(np.zeros(n), np.eye(n), 1)
    #Y=X.dot(Beta)
    Y=X.dot(Beta)+ep.T
    return Y,X,Beta,ep.T 

Y,X,Beta,ep=generate_task(p,n,0.6,2,10)
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33)
clr = Ridge(alpha=0.1, fit_intercept=False, normalize=False, copy_X=True, max_iter=None, tol=0.001, solver='auto')
Y_tr=Y_train.ravel()
Y_te=Y_test.ravel()
clr.fit(X_train,Y_tr)
plt.plot(Y_te, label='Original')
plt.plot(clr.predict(X_test), label = 'Estimate')
```

Which results in: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGh1F.png
in comparison to my own function:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQHVD.png
which to my taste is kind of unlikely, especially, when said built-in function returns nearly identical results for diffrent tasks.
Edit: As it occured presented example uses IID matrix, but problem is the same for correleted cases.